# Is there an easier way to remove '-' in front of every string in an array

Tags: python

I am searching for an easier way to remove the '-' in front of each string in a list. (only the first '-' if there is one in front of the string)

```
note_tmp = [
    "-some-text",
    "-other text",
    "another-one",
    "-text number four"
]
note_done = []
for note in note_tmp:
    if note.startswith("-"):
        note_done.append(note[1:])
    else:
        note_done.append(note)

print(note_done)
```

I thing this can be written much easier...

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I don't know if there is some method; but i think; those methods would at last will do the same; ie. iteration and checking; then modifying and appending; which ofcourse you have done.  Also one thing can be shortened; remove else block and directly modify the main list(if there is a safe copy somewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.lstrip('-')` should do:

```
In [83]: note_tmp = [
    ...:     "-some-text",
    ...:     "-other text",
    ...:     "another-one",
    ...:     "-text number four"
    ...: ]

In [84]: [s.lstrip('-') for s in note_tmp]
Out[84]: ['some-text', 'other text', 'another-one', 'text number four']
```

> S.lstrip([chars]) -> str
>
> Return a copy of the string S with leading whitespace removed.
>   If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.

Comment: @swiftlynx Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) with *list comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
my_list = [
    "-some-text",
    "-other text",
    "another-one",
    "-text number four"
]

new_list = [s.lstrip('-') for s in my_list]
```

where `new_list` will hold value:

```
['some-text', 'other text', 'another-one', 'text number four']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an alternative approach, using list slicing and list comprehension;

```
note_tmp = [
        "-some-text",
        "-other text",
        "another-one",
        "-text number four"
    ]

new_note_tmp = [x[1:] if x[0] == '-' else x for x in note_tmp]

print(new_note_tmp)

>>>['some-text', 'other text', 'another-one', 'text number four']
```

Comment: list comprehension isn't making it any shorter

Comment: I beg to differ, as it is quite clearly 5 lines shorter. Furthermore, no-one has asked for a 'shorter' solution.

Comment: i can make it one line code; but that is also not shorter because I think shorter means less in time- space complexity; and not the lines that the code acquires.

Comment: But it does have the benefit that it only removes one '-' at the start of the string, unlike the .lstrip() versions.